# Xcode 6 - Thread 1 SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading

I'm trying to put Ad's intro my xcode project but everytime I run the project it stops and i get the "Thread 1 SIGABRT error" on the line that says

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)];
```

the full code for this section is -

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-1249154779941831/7243806389";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    SoundButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

the code is GADBannerview.h

```
//
//  GADBannerView.h
//  Google Mobile Ads SDK
//
//  Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "GADAdSize.h"
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"
#import "GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h"
#import "GADModules.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"
#import "GADRequestError.h"

@interface GADBannerView : UIView

#pragma mark Initialization

- (instancetype)initWithAdSize:(GADAdSize)adSize origin:(CGPoint)origin;


- (instancetype)initWithAdSize:(GADAdSize)adSize;

#pragma mark Pre-Request


@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *adUnitID;

@property(nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *rootViewController;


@property(nonatomic, assign) GADAdSize adSize;

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<GADBannerViewDelegate> delegate;


@property(nonatomic, weak) id<GADInAppPurchaseDelegate> inAppPurchaseDelegate;

#pragma mark Making an Ad Request

- (void)loadRequest:(GADRequest *)request;

#pragma mark Ad Request
@property(nonatomic, readonly, assign) BOOL hasAutoRefreshed;

#pragma mark Mediation

@property(nonatomic, readonly, weak) NSString *adNetworkClassName;


@property(nonatomic, readonly, weak) UIView *mediatedAdView
    __attribute__((deprecated("Use adNetworkClassName.")));

@end
```

Comment: the only other code is -    GADBannerView *bannerView_; in my view controller.h

Comment: But can you show some code in `GADBannerView.m`? Your tagging of multi-threading also suggests there is more to this. Show the multi-threading part, too.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [swift] ?

Comment: there is no GADBannerView.M but there is a .h

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Other Linker Flags" with `-ObjC -alll_load`?

Comment: I will add that as answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to set in "Other Linker Flags" with `-ObjC -alll_load`, and it should work.

Comment: How did you identify from question description, that this could be an issue?